# Golang: io.Copy(httpReponseWriter, os.File) vs. http.ServeFile()

Tags: css, http, go

Before realizing that the http package has a builtin ServeFile method, I implemented a static handler more or less like this:

```
func StaticHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    filename := mux.Vars(r)["static"] // using gorilla/mux
    f, err := os.Open(fmt.Sprintf("%v/static/%v", webroot, filename))

    if err != nil {
        http.NotFound(w, r)
        return
    }

    defer f.Close()

    io.Copy(w, f)
}
```

And, for example, linked my style sheet and images this way:

```
<img href="/image.jpg" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheet.css">
```

This worked just fine, except for one thing: my linked stylesheet was not being applied by the browser (tested in Chrome, Firefox, Midori). The stylesheet could be served ( visiting MYSITE/stylesheet.css displayed the css plaintext) and images would load normally in a page, but none of my pages would have any style.

Any ideas as to why?

Comment: What are the headers of such response?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Looks like this: 
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 30 Oct 2013 18:23:10 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Setting the header worked (duh. Still getting familiar with this web-stuff, apparently). Post an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: I'm actually really surprised that my code worked for images. The built-in server will determine the content-type of the byte stream going through it, but won't try to guess the nature of a text doc (other than html)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple answer: headers were wrong.

Go will supply correct headers for html, jpgs, and pngs, but css (and js) files are left as "text/plain" rather than "text/css" and "text/javascript".

[Go source](http://golang.org/src/pkg/net/http/fs.go?s=3056:3160#L124) shows the handling being invoked, I believe.

Anyways, setting the content type via:

```
w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/css; charset=utf-8")
```

Did the trick.